# Setting up a Entity Framework Code First Database on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I successfully created my first Entity Framework Code first project using SQL Server CE. The database tables were created automatically and all was well.

I then changed my connection string to point to a SQL Server database I'd created and expected it to autogenerate the tables. It didn't and instead complained about the tables not existing.

After some reading I found that I needed to add an initializer to my `App_Start` method.

I tried:

```
// Method 1
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<EFContext>());
```

But this didn't work at first because it couldn't find an EdmMetaData table to discover if the model had changed.

So I tried adding:

```
// Method 2
Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<EFContext>());
```

But this didn't work because I'd already created the database, and when I removed the database it still didn't work because the user I was logging in as didn't have create database privileges.

I finally tried:

```
// Method 3
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<EFContext>());
```

Which worked, but I don't really want to drop the db every time. So once it ran and added the EdmMetaData table I replaced it with method 1 and that now works fine.

Although this method works, it doesn't feel as elegant as when I was using SQL Server CE and I've not found someone suggesting that you use this method.

So, am I missing something and is there an easier, more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1 and 2 expects that database doesn't exist yet. They don't work if you create database manually. If you need EF to create tables in existing database you must create [custom database initializer](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2011/05/30/creating-a-code-first-database-initializer-strategy.aspx).